# Sum of column minus column from another table - SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: https://i.imgur.com/uQWh8NJ.png]

I need help with this SQL statement.

I don't know how to get a null or zero for empty fields in subsalary column
or how not to duplicate the records.

Comment: No images, please. Use formatted text instead. And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: You may want to see how others post questions here... links to pics don't always work in some places and websites that host these pics tend to go offline.  When that happens your question will be vague to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY` will help:

```
SELECT T1.Emp_Id, T1.Safe_Id, T1.Salary,
       SUM(T2.SubSalary) AS SubSalary,
       (T1.Salary - SUM(T2.SubSalary)) AS [Difference]
FROM TableOne T1
LEFT JOIN TableTwo T2 ON T2.Emp_Id = T1.Emp_Id AND T2.Safe_Id = T1.Safe_Id
GROUP BY T1.Emp_Id, T1.Safe_Id, T1.Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick

```
 SELECT t1.EmployeeID
    ,t1.safe_id
    ,MAX(t1.salary)
    ,SUM(COALESCE(t2.subSalary, 0)) AS SubSalary
    ,MAX(t1.salary) - SUM(COALESCE(t2.subSalary, 0)) AS difference
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
    AND t1.safe_id = t2.safe_id
GROUP BY t1.EmployeeID
    ,t1.safe_id
```